# Python: create a lag (t-1) data structure of multiple elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I'm having trouble creating a time lag column for my data. It works fine when I do it for a dataframe with a just a kind of elements, but it doesn't not work fine, when I have different elements. For example, my dataset looks something like this:

[image]

when using the command suggested:

```
data1['lag_t'] = data1['total_tax'].shift(1)
```

I get a result like this:

[image]

As you can see, it just displace all the 'total_tax' value one row. However, I need to do this lag for EACH ONE of the **id_inf** (as separate items).

My dataset is really huge, so I need to find a way to solve this issue. So I can get as a result a table like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on index and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

```
# an example with random data.
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [9,9,9,54,54,54],'total_tax':[5,6,7,1,2,3]}).set_index('id')

data1['lag_t'] = data1.groupby(level=0)['total_tax'].apply(lambda x: x.shift())

print (data1)

    tax  lag_t
id            
9     5    NaN
9     6    5.0
9     7    6.0
54    1    NaN
54    2    1.0
54    3    2.0
```